# Solr query: prefer phrase over occurrence of single words, but accept both

Tags: solr

For our Solr product search a new requirement has been specified:
A given list of terms needs to be queried over some fields, and the score shall be higher, when they are found as a phrase than when all of the terms occur in a different order, and this must be scored higher than the occurrence of only some of the terms in a single field, or all of the fields occurring but in different fields. Also some of the fields need higher scores than other (title higher than description).

I have thought of a solution like this (with a, b, c being search terms, could be any number of them):

```
q=title:"a b c"^40.0 or title:(+a +b +c)^20.0 or title:(a b c)^5.0 or description:"a b c"^30.0 or description:(+a +b +c)^10.0 or description:(a b c)^3.0 ...
```

Some fields need a different treatment, e.g. person names should be scored higher, when they match exactly, but shall also be searched fuzzy, like that:

```
q=name:(+a +b +c)^40.0 or name:(a b c)^20.0 or name (a~0.9 b~0.9 c~0.9)^5.0 etc.
```

Other criteria has to be matched exactly to model certain restrictions, like

```
active:true and publicationDate[* to now] ...
```

Is this a valid solution? Are there better ones?

As I have no practical experience with the edismax parser, I am not quite sure, if it would be able to solve my problem.

Comment: Seems like an acceptable solution, try and see. Impossible to say anything about performance without testing on your own index.